# RSA-based encryption scheme and random oracle

Tags: rsa, random-oracle-model

I don't really get how this problem should be solved. My main issue is with the random oracle generally, a short explanation of ROs and how they are used in such proofs maybe with this example will hopefully clear that up.

Consider the RSA-based encryption scheme in which a user encrypts a message
$m ∈ \{0,1\}^{l}$ with respect to the public key $(N, e)$ by  computing $$m':= H(m)\|m$$
and  outputting  the  ciphertext $$c:=m'^{e} \mod N.$$ (Here,let $H:=\{0,1\}^{l}→ \{0,1\}^{n}$ and assume $l+n<\|N\|$, the bit-length of $N$). The receiver recovers m'
in the usual way and verifies that it has the correct form before outputting
the $l$ least-significant bits as $m$. Prove or disprove that this scheme is CCA-secure if H is modeled as a random oracle.

Comment: [Random oracle (RO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle) quite clear, right?

Comment: @kelalaka yes, as a concept on its own.. don't know how to use it practically in the example.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the weaker IND-CPA case. "Textbook RSA" is not CPA-secure since it is deterministic. Hence, you can encrypt both your messages and compare them with the challenge-message. Is your modified RSA scheme also deterministic?

Hint: $H$ is chosen at the beginning of the CPA-game.